# Activity from Page Tab application - without Canvas

Tags: facebook, android-activity, tabs

Is there a way to post activity just from a page tab application?

I managed to post activity, but the app must be configured to be App on Facebook (with canvas). 
This means the link to the application is *http://apps.facebook.com/...* - I just want that link to be on page tab application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your Facebook app settings set the Page Tab URL and the Secure Page Tab URL. Then add the app to your Facebook page by using this dialog: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_PAGE_TAB_URL .

**UPDATE**:
I would suggest you make a redirect. You can check whether the app is shown inside a page tab using the following function (PHP):

```
function referrerIsFacebookCanvasApp() {
    if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "apps.facebook.com") === true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But be careful - referrer headers can be faked.

**UPDATE 2** (based on your latest comment):
I guess the only way to solve your problem is to store the action ids together with the page id of the page, where the action has been published, then read the GET request parameters, which are passed like this:

https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE/?fb_source=timeline_og&fb_action_ids=THE_ACTION_ID&fb_action_types=YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE%3ADO_SOMETHING&...

or this

http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https://YOUR_SITE.com/?type=OBJECT_TYPE&locale=en_US&title=TITLE&image=thumb.png&description=DESCRIPTION&fb_action_ids=ACTION_ID&fb_action_types=YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE%3ADO_SOMETHING&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=AGGREGATION_ID&...

(you should be able to do that by reading `parent.location` )
and then redirect accordingly.

Comment: yes, did that... this is not the issue. The issue is that, from that application, I'll post something on activity, using OpenGraph actions.
And the link to the application will be the one setup on canvas. I want that link to be to page-tab.

Comment: I don't get your problem. Do you want the link of the activity point to your page tab?

Comment: Yes. If i post to activity from the application, the link points to canvas application. I want it to point to page tab application.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the idea but in my app, I need the signed response from Facebook, that is POST-ed.

Comment: That should be no problem. You should be able to read the Facebook signed request as long as your app is loaded inside a canvas on Facebook. Just try it out: `echo $_REQUEST["signed_request"];`

Comment: yes :( but this is the canvas version, so i don't have page id in signed request :(

Comment: But when you redirect to the page tab, you should be able to read the signed_request there. Have you tried that?

Comment: can't redirect to page tab as I don't have page tab id :( the application is shown on more than one page tab, so i'd need to know exactly the page tab - even in canvas mode - so i'd be able to redirect to proper page tab

Comment: UPDATE 2: yes, that would be an option if i'd be able to add page id automatically somehow in opengraph? Remember, this is shown on more pages :(

RE - i think this can be somehow added in opengraph - when editing action type... i'll check more of this tomorrow :)

Comment: You don't have to append the page ID to the action. You need to store it together with the action ID in your data base so that later you can associate the page where the action was published by looking on the action ID.

Comment: yes, but still i have the application canvas url - in activity listing - without any activity id, page id...

Comment: that's true and I don't think you can find a solution for that one. Maybe you should post another updated and more detailed question here on SO... Anyway, good luck! Sry I couldn't help you.